# how can i get the fullpath to a file named bigfifo.sv using tcl to querty the project file?

Tags: fpga, vivado

In vivado how can I get the fullpath to a file named bigfifo.sv?

When I run get_files at the TCL prompt, it just prints a long list of the fullpath of all the files in my project.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here, in the  missing and "reverse engineered" Command Reference for get_files:

```
Vivado get_<object> -filter
```

## Filter Flag

The -filter option is available on many Vivado `get_*` commands to filter the returned results based on properties of the objects.

### Usage

The basic syntax is:

```bash
get_<objects> [-filter <expression>]
```

Where `<expression>` is a filtering expression to apply to the returned objects.

### Filtering Expressions

The filtering expression can use to match and compare against an object's properties:

- Logical/Numeric/Boolean Operators:

  ```
  # Logical:  !    ==    !=     &&   ||
  # Numeric:  ==   <    <=    >     >=
  # Boolean:   true   false

  get_cells -filter {REF_NAME == FD}

  get_nets -filter {FANOUT > 100 && IS_GLOBAL == false}
  ```

- String Match

  ```
  # exact string match
  get_files -filter {NAME =~ C:/myproj/abc.vhd}

  #wildcard match
  get_files -filter {NAME =~ */files.*}

  #regexp match
  get_files -filter -regexp {NAME =~ .*/abc/.*/}

  #case insenstive match
  get_files -filter -nocase {NAME =~ files/MyFileCrazyCase.VhDl}
  ```
- Not String

  ```
  # Files that do not contain abc
  get_file -filter {NAME !~ *abc*}
  ```

### Finding Objects Properties

```
# Example procedure to find an objects properties

tcl> set alist [get_files]
 
tcl> report_property [lindex $alist 0]

Property            Type     Read-only  Value
CLASS               string   true       file
CORE_CONTAINER      string   true      
FILE_TYPE           enum     false      VHDL 2008
IS_AVAILABLE        bool     true       1
IS_ENABLED          bool     false      1
IS_GENERATED        bool     true       0
IS_GLOBAL_INCLUDE   bool     false      0
IS_NGC_WRAPPER      bool     true       0
LIBRARY             string   false      work
NAME                string   true       C:/myproj/myfile.vhd
NEEDS_REFRESH       bool     true       0
PATH_MODE           enum     false      RelativeFirst
USED_IN             string*  false      synthesis simulation
USED_IN_SIMULATION  bool     false      1
USED_IN_SYNTHESIS   bool     false      1
```

For example:

### Special Cases

- The `NAME` property always matches against the full hierarchical name.
- Boolean properties like `IS_PRIMITIVE` can be used directly without an explicit comparison:

  ```
  get_cells -filter IS_PRIMITIVE
  ```
- Use parentheses to group expressions:

  ```
  get_cells -filter {(REF_NAME =~ *FD*) && !(IS_PRIMITIVE)}
  ```

### Combining with -regexp

The `-regexp` option can be added to enable regular expression matching in the filter expression:

```
get_cells -filter -regexp {REF_NAME =~ .*FD.*}
```

### Combining with -nocase

The `-nocase` option can be added to perform case-insensitive matching:

```
get_cells -filter -regexp -nocase {NAME =~ .*validfor.*}
```

### Hierarchical Filtering

By default `-filter` filters objects at the current level of hierarchy.

Add `-hierarchical` to filter objects hierarchically across all levels:

```
get_cells -hierarchical -filter {IS_PRIMITIVE}
```

### Filtering Collections

The `filter` command can filter any Tcl collection, including results previously returned from `get_*`:

```
set allCells [get_cells]
set primCells [filter $allCells IS_PRIMITIVE]
```

In summary, `-filter` is a powerful way to filter results from the Vivado database based on object properties. The filtering expression syntax offers many flexible ways to select objects.

## `get_files`

### Description

Retrieves a list of files in the current project that match a specified search pattern. The default behavior is to retrieve all files in the project. Use command arguments to filter and customize the output as needed.

### Syntax

```
get_files 
[-regexp] 
[-nocase] 
[-filter <arg>] 
[-compile_order <arg>] 
[-used_in <arg>] 
[-references] 
[-all] 
[-of_objects <args>] 
[-quiet] 
[-verbose] 
[<patterns>]
```

### Returns

List of file objects.

### Arguments

Certainly! Below is a consolidated table that includes all the arguments along with their descriptions for the `get_files` command in Vivado:

| Argument | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `[-regexp]` | Interpret patterns as full regular expressions. |
| `[-nocase]` | Perform case-insensitive matching. )Only valid with -regexp) |
| `[-filter <arg>]` | Filter list with an expression. |
| `[-compile_order <arg>]` | Get files by type and in compilation order. (Must use with -used_in) |
| `[-used_in <arg>]` | Get files used in a specific step. (Must use with -compile_order) |
| `[-references]` | Get files referenced in the provided objects. (Must use with -of_objects.) |
| `[-all]` | Include all internal files. |
| `[-of_objects <args>]` | Get 'file' objects of specific types. only valid with file types: file, fileset, ip, reconfig_module |
| `[-quiet]` | Suppress command errors. |
| `[-verbose]` | Suspend message limits during command execution. |
| `[<patterns>]` | Match file names against patterns. (Default: *.) |

-

### Examples

1. Get VHDL files used in simulation:

   ```bash
   get_files -filter {FILE_TYPE == VHDL && USED_IN =~ simulation*}
   ```
2. Get source files used in simulation:

   ```bash
   get_files -compile_order sources -used_in simulation
   ```
3. Get files associated with a specific IP core used in synthesis:

   ```bash
   get_files -compile_order sources -used_in synthesis -of [get_files ip.xci]
   ```
4. Get files from specific filesets:

   ```bash
   get_files -of [get_filesets {sources_1 constrs_1}]
   ```
5. Find a specific file without knowing its full path in the project:

   ```
   set file_obj [get_files -filter {NAME =~ */mycool.bd}
   ```
6. List all vhdl files

```
set files_vhdl [get_files -filter {NAME =~ */*.vhd}]
foreach f $files_vhdl {puts $f}
```

### File Object Props

```
CLASS               string   true       file
CORE_CONTAINER      string   true      
FILE_TYPE           enum     false      VHDL 2008
IS_AVAILABLE        bool     true       1
IS_ENABLED          bool     false      1
IS_GENERATED        bool     true       0
IS_GLOBAL_INCLUDE   bool     false      0
IS_NGC_WRAPPER      bool     true       0
LIBRARY             string   false      work
NAME                string   true       C:/myproj/myfile.vhd
NEEDS_REFRESH       bool     true       0
PATH_MODE           enum     false      RelativeFirst
USED_IN             string*  false      synthesis simulation
USED_IN_SIMULATION  bool     false      1
USED_IN_SYNTHESIS   bool     false      1
```

### Categories

- Object
- Project

### See Also

- `report_compile_order`
- `report_property`

---